# Xpath field repetition

Tags: python, xpath

I want to put it in data,And I'm going to insert **MySQL**,But the resulting content field is repeated,I think it's my for circular logic error,So how do I change?

---

```
def get_user_data(self,start_url):
        html = requests.get(url=start_url,headers=self.headers,cookies=self.cookies).content
        selector = etree.fromstring(html,etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
        contents = selector.xpath('//span[@class="ctt"]/text()')
        times = selector.xpath('//span[@class="ct"]/text()')
        data = {}
        for each_text in contents:
            data['content'] = each_text
        for each_time in times:
            month_day, time, device = each_time.split(maxsplit=2)
            data['mobile_phone'] = device
            data['create_time'] = month_day + '\n' + time
            data['crawl_time'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            self.mysql.insert(data)
```